# Parsing a UILabel

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have a UILabel for a calculator (this is for the CS193P graphing calculator).  I would like to parse the current operand, which would be the rightmost value following an operator.  For example, X+3 would need to parse the 3.

What is the easiest way to do this?  Also, in trying to assign values back-and-forth between an NSString and this  UILabel, I've received casting errors.  Could someone explain the rationale behind having UILabel and NSString requiring explicit casting?  It seems to me they should both be treated as strings.

Comment: casting: you dont need to cast. I hope you are writing: `myLabel.text = myString` and **not** `myLabel=myString`

Comment: Showing the actual code you’ve written and the actual compiler errors will help you to get better answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use .text property of UILabel which is an NSString. Therefore you don't need casting while using text property.

Also you can use `characterAtIndex:` method of NSStrings with the length method of your label's text.

like this  `[yourLabel.text characterAtIndex:([yourLabel.text length]-1)];`

Comment: Thank you, indeed I was forgetting to use .text on the assignment.  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Casting-problem:

I hope you've written `myLabel.text = myString` and not `myLabel=myString`

Parsing-problem:

I think the best way to do this is by creating a [Syntax-Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) and then working only with the syntax-tree. To create this I would just iterate through the text beginning at the front and read the text char by char.